# Simplify Where-Object to filter multiple same object

Tags: powershell

How would you simplify the following script?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -properties * | Where-Object {
  $_.OperatingSystem -like "*2003*" -and
  $_.OperatingSystem -like "*2008*" -and
  $_.OperatingSystem -like "*2012*"
} | sort name | ft name, description, OperatingSystem
```

I've been looking for a while on this one and would like some help. I know I could simplify by using `"*20*"` and I will get my result but I'd like to know how to use multiple criteria (i.e. XP, Windows 10, etc.).

Comment: Maybe a quibble, but what you have there is never going to return anything as long as those conditions are ANDed instead of ORed.

Comment: how about actually using tat -Filter thingie for a start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `-match` operator with a regex pattern

```
...|?{$_.operatingsystem -match "2008|2012|XP" }
```

Know that `?` is an alias for `Where-Object`. See the output of `Get-Alias` for more of these.

Comment: I was looking for the acknowledgement. Done